# How many system calls is performed?

Tags: linux, system, call

My question is about system calls in Linux. I have heard that a simple program that just prints "hello world" in the prompt can require up to 50 system calls. Is this correct and if so what is happening in all these calls?

Comment: Number of system calls will depend greatly on the language and compile options.  So I wouldn't say that many are *required*.

Comment: I have heard that as much as 230% of numbers mentioned in computer science discussions are blown out of proportion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the tool `strace` to print out syscalls. Just start any program with strace in front of it, like this: `strace echo "Hello World"`. You may need to be root user to make use of it.

Here is the [manpage for strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)

Comment: Yes i know that, but my question is not how many system calls are exactly performed but why so many are requried. A system call is needed to execute a new process, but what more is needed to run a simple program like this?

Comment: you don't seriously expect us the explain each call, do you?... go through the list, google (a lot), post a question about one of them if it's still unclear.

Comment: Actually, this is exactly what you were asking ;-). What each of them do is exactly what strace will print. It may not be very readable without a lot of digging, but it will be the most precise answer you can get for your system and for the command you are running.

Comment: @user3213297: "execute a new process" is a system call, but not in the process you're running.  The only actually necessary system calls for a Hello-World are `write(stdout, "Hello World", 11)` and `exit()`.  Any others are coming from the runtime library of the language you used for development, and are there to support features used in more complex programs.

Answer (score 0):

So even though the software is simple, you still need to account for everything that is going on with hardware behind the scenes. In your example, "a simple program that just prints 'hello world' in the prompt", a lot is going on. To begin thinking about why there are so many syscalls involved, ask yourself what the underlying mechanism is to take a file from disk and execute its instructions on the CPU (part of which involve writing to the output stream and changing pixels on the monitor). Every time our userspace application wants access to these hardware, we need to make a syscall. In the case of hello world, we would need to create a linkage between our hello-world.c file and the stdio.h file. This would require a number of syscalls. Then we would need to map the linked files into memory, (so the processor can execute) requiring more syscalls. And so on.

Answer (score -1):

In Linux (and Windows), system calls are typically executed by passing the SysCallId in the EAX register and executing either `int 0x80` (software interrupt) or `SYSENTER` (new instruction)

Basically this transfers control to the kernel, kernel will then find the function to execute in its system service table using the index passed and execute it.